# Socket.io on webserver

Tags: socket.io

How to use socket.io live on website rather than localhost ? Please need some guidelines I'm learning this technology for asynchronous request-response but how do I actually use it on live website

Comment: is there any difference between using socket.io based website locally and remotely?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this.
One solution is:
1. start socket server on machine1(ip1)
2. start a nginx/apache or any other proxy server on machine2(ip2) and map the socket server address(of machine 1) in its conf file.
3. put this new machine2 url on your live website.
Let me know if you face any problems while doing all this configuration. This is just the high level overview that i have provided here.

Comment: Thanks for reply rajeev i have managed to start the server on my machine and access it from several devices using the IP of the Machine currently it runs on port 3000 i.e the Access URL is http://localhost:3000 whereas i access the server using IP address of machine i.e 192.168.0.100:3000 on which socket.io server is initialised. However i m still unclear how to map this config to live website. Please guide if i'm doing something wrong in my local config & can u please help me from here further with some little more details? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do i need a hosting service which provides support for Node.js as well ?

Comment: Hi Harsh,
I am not clear as to what "mapping in live website means to you". If you could tell me what you exactly want to achieve.. i may be able to assist further..

Comment: Hi rajeev i want to setup an app server for Node